# url shortening in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the simplest way to shorten my URLs using python 3. The libraries that I have seen so far are outdated and no longer maintained. People will see these URLs so I want to use something trustworthy like tinyurl or bit.ly or goog.gl

Given a URL, how can I pass it into a function that will shorten it?

What is the best way to programmatically shorten URLs in 2020?

Answer (score 1):

Try this script.

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576918/

Usage:

```
>>> import short_url
>>> url = short_url.encode_url(12)
>>> print url
LhKA
>>> key = short_url.decode_url(url)
>>> print key
12
```

Answer (score 1):

For bit.ly, you can use their API, which is documented [here](https://dev.bitly.com/v4_documentation.html). If it's a simple application, you should probably start with a generic access token (get one [here](https://app.bitly.com/Bk5v6SUREPe/bitlinks/?actions=accountMain&actions=profile&actions=accessToken))

Once you have an access token, you can post a request:

- method: POST
- URL: https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten
- Headers:

  ````
  Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_GOES_HERE```
  ````
- Body:

  ````
    "domain": "bit.ly",
    "long_url": "https://www.my-url.com"
  }```
  ````

the response is:

```
{
"created_at": "2020-05-31T06:20:30+0000",
"id": "...",
"link": "<bit-ly link comes here",
"custom_bitlinks": [],
"long_url": "https://www.my-url.com/",
... some other stuff.
```

In python, it would look like:

```
headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json", 
    "Authorization": "Bearer <TOKEN_GOES_HERE"
}

body = json.dumps({
  "domain": "bit.ly",
  "long_url": "https://www.my-url.com"
})

URL = "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten"
res = requests.post(url = URL, data = body, headers = headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can refer bit.ly for sortener url, for this you need to create your account on bitly from their you genrate access_token that need to integrate your account with your code and sort the url, as well as it store that url into your bitly account. 
**pip install bitlyshortener**

```
from bitlyshortener import Shortener
# get access token from bitly
tokens_pool = ['your_bitly_access_token']
shortener = Shortener(tokens=tokens_pool, max_cache_size=128)
# get url into list
urls = []
url = input("Enter url: ")
urls.append(url)

# shorten using bitly
short_urls = shortener.shorten_urls_to_dict(url)
print("short urls: ", short_urls[url])
```